# Is it possible to use AppleScript to perform non-shell scripts?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, tree, applescript

my question probably has a simple answer but I'm far from an expert when it comes to this stuff.

I've installed the 3rd party command line software "tree" on my Mac so that I can print a file directory structure to a text file for record keeping.

Now I'm trying to write a short AppleScript that performs the tree command mentioned above, however since tree isn't a native shell script in Terminal, I get the error: **"sh: tree: command not found"**

Is it possible to get AppleScript to perform a tree command without it opening up Terminal and literally just keystroking in the command, ideally I'd like the script to run in the background without having to run any apps.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. The `tree` _command_ isn't a _script_, it's a _binary executable_. 2. The `do shell script` _command_ doesn't open the **Terminal** _application_. 3. You need to use the _fully qualified pathname_ of the _command executable_ because the `tree` _command_ is likely not within the `PATH` passed to **AppleScript** when calling the `do shell script` _command_, which is: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` 4. RE:  "and literally just keystroking in the command, ideally I'd like the script to run in the background without having to run any apps." You are goin to have to clarify what you mean by that!

Comment: @user3439894 thanks for the info. So is there a way to use the "do shell script" command to use "tree" or should I be using a different command entirely?

Comment: In order to execute a _shell command_ in basic vanilla **AppleScript** that is what the `do shell script` _command_ is for. -- Before I provide any further information you need to clarify what was asked in point 4 of my first comment. RE: "and literally just keystroking in the command, ideally I'd like the script to run in the background without having to run any apps." -- What is it you mean by this and what is the end goal here?

Comment: @user3439894 when I said "and literally just keystroking in the command, ideally I'd like the script to run in the background without having to run any apps" I meant I didn't want to have to have AppleScript open up terminal and write in the command in plain text, that's what I meant by the term "keystroking", perhaps I didn't use the term correctly. And the second half of the comment just means I would rather AppleScript run the command in the background rather than launching the terminal.app

Answer (score 0):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is one way of running the *third-party utility* `tree` *command* via **AppleScript**  and have its *output* written to a *text file*:

- Change `"/path/to/tree <command options>"` to the appropriate *fully qualified pathname* of the `tree` *command* along with its *options*.
- Change `"/path/to/tree_output.txt"` to the appropriate *fully qualified pathname* of the *text file* where the *output* of the `tree` *command* is to be written.

```
set treeOutput to do shell script "/path/to/tree <command options>"

set filePathnameToSaveTreeOutputTo to "/path/to/tree_output.txt"


my writeToFile(treeOutput, filePathnameToSaveTreeOutputTo, true)


--  # Handler

on writeToFile(theData, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try
        set theFile to theFile as string
        if theFile contains "/" then
            set theOpenedFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        else
            set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission
        end if
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        write theData to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        close access theOpenedFile
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try
        return false
    end try
end writeToFile
```

---

**Notes:**

- The *fully qualified pathname* for `filePathnameToSaveTreeOutputTo` can be an **HFS path** or a **POSIX path**.
- The *fully qualified pathname* for the `tree` *command* needs to be a **POSIX path**, as well as the target *directory* the `tree` *command* will scan.
- The `writeToFile(theData, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)` *handler* is a slightly modified *handler* from [Reading and Writing Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ReadandWriteFiles.html)
- The *handler* from the linked **Apple** support document was modified to handle both **POSIX** and **HFS+** *file paths*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: @thanks-pete, Does my answer cover what you want to do?